# Can't get vundle or neobundle to work on GVim on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows, vim, git, gvim, vimrc

Can't get these add-ons (**vundle** or **neobundle**) to work on my Windows 7 machine.
Everytime I try to install plugins I'm getting the following error messages:

```
Error detected while processing function neobundle#commands#check...neobundle#commands#install..
<SNR>21_install...neobundle#installer#sync..neobundle#util#system: 
line 7: E484: Can't open file C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp\VIo3342.tmp 
Error detected while processing function neobundle#commands#check: 
line 18: E171: Missing :endif
```

When I run `:sh` from within GVim, `cmd.exe` opens up where **git** or **curl** function properly.

My **_vimrc** file:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction


" My Settings
if has('vim_starting')
   set nocompatible               " Be iMproved

   " Required:
   set runtimepath+=~/vimfiles/bundle/neobundle.vim/
endif

" Required:
call neobundle#begin(expand('~/vimfiles/bundle/'))

" Let NeoBundle manage NeoBundle
" Required:
NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'

" My Bundles here:
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet.vim'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'
NeoBundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
NeoBundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
NeoBundle 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'

" You can specify revision/branch/tag.
" NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimshell', { 'rev' : '3787e5' }

call neobundle#end()

" Required:
filetype plugin indent on

" If there are uninstalled bundles found on startup,
" this will conveniently prompt you to install them.
NeoBundleCheck
```

I have a feeling that the issue here is that GVim tries to access `Documents and Settings` (with spaces) instead of just `C:\Users\user`...

**Update 1**

Must be something related to my environmental variables or the way GVim launched. Tried to use the same config and GVim build on a fresh Windows VM and didn't have any issues there...

Are there any configuration settings I should look for/check on my computer?

Comment: Does the directory exist, and is it accessible from within Vim (which is 32 or 64-bit)?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Yes, the directory exists on my machine and it resolves to c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\. I'm using 32bit version of Vim. How can I check if this directory is accessible from within GVim/Vim?

Comment: How about `:edit C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp\test.txt`?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Hm, interesting. I was able to open the file in this directory (there was also test.txt.swp file in there too) but I can't save my changes to this file. Getting "E212: Can't open file for writing" when I click SAVE button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

The issue was with my **User** environment variables that I had to reset to:

```
%HOME% = %USERPROFILE%
%TEMP% = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
%TMP% = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```